# Fast huffman decode

Tags: android, scala, huffman-code

I have written a huffman compression/decompression in Scala. When decoding small files it takes seconds, but when decoding larger file it takes an extremely long time. Any suggestions for how I could speed this process up?

```
def lookup(list:List[Int],list2:List[(Char,List[Int])]): Option[String]={
  val mutableListBuffer = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(list2: _*)
  var option:Option[String]= None
  for(i <- 0 until mutableListBuffer.length){  
    if(mutableListBuffer(i)._2 == list){
      option =  Some(mutableListBuffer(i)._1.toString)         
    }
  }
  option
}

/*
*Decode function for matching groups of bits in a list to characters    in     the HCodeMap
*@returns String
*/
def decode(acc:Int,s:String,list:(List[Int],List[(Char,List[Int])])):String ={
  var s = ""
  var accum = 1
  val listp1 = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(list._1: _*)
  val listp2 = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(list._2: _*)
  var tupList = (listp1,listp2)

  while(!tupList._1.isEmpty){
    if(lookup(tupList._1.take(accum).toList,tupList._2.toList).isDefined){
      println(accum)
      s = s ++ lookup(tupList._1.take(accum).toList,tupList._2.toList).getOrElse("a")
      Log.d("MyTAG", "de" + s)  
      tupList._1.remove(0,accum)
      accum = accum - accum + 1
    }
    else{
      accum =  accum + 1
    }        
  }
  s
}
```

The code is executing on an Android device so using recursion wasn't an effective option, neither was using immutable lists. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained what the parameters were, and named them more informatively. Also, there's some oddities - `acc` is the first arg to decode, but not used.  It's really difficult to see what the code is doing.

Comment: You're right with acc being redundant. The second is the string to decode. The third is a pair containing the lists of bits to be decoded along with the codemap containing characters and their bit representation. I had it in a more recursive manner, but had to rewrite this because android was reporting stack overflow errors due to the recursion.

Comment: And why do you use `tupList`? It does nothing that using the underlying `listp1` and `listp2` directly wouldn't do, only clearer. I think you should clear up this code first before worrying about optimising it,,.,it will make it clearer to see where the improvements can be.

Comment: Unless I explicitly create the tupList myself I get a "recursive value list needs type" error.

Comment: recursive value list needs type val list = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(list: _*). This was the reason for getting creating the tupList variable. I had this using recursion originally, but when transfering to Android I got stack overflow errors.

Comment: I think that's some other problem. It compiles just fine when I change `tupList._1` to `listp1` and `tuplIst._2` to `listp2`. Please post an example call to decode, and its output. And what's this statement: `accum = accum - accum + 1` - that just sets `accum` to `1` in a pointlessly complicated way

Comment: You might as well leave listp2 as a List, since you never modify it, only to turn it into a List again. You use mutable ArrayBuffer in lookup, but never modify it. It's all very confused - and probably the time goes in all the unnecessary conversion back and forth

Comment: My mistake you were correct about the first part, but as I say my issue isn't that it doesn't decode, just the length of time it takes on large text to decode. A few seconds to encode and a few minutes to decode. I'll take your suggestions on board and see if it speeds the decode up. Thanks for the advice it's much appreciated. This was a quick conversion from recursion to iteration, so I'm aware of the sloppy code :)

Comment: Right, and it's all the messing about with conversions, I predict, And calling lookup twice in the loop, etc, etc. . The `getOrElse` is redundant, you've already checked `lookup` returns a Some().  Improved code coming as an answer in am in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may belong in codereview instead, but here's code I think is a direct equivalent of yours, without any conversion to ArrayBuffers (which are not necessary). The list manipulations are fairly efficient being just take and drop, and list traversal so I think you're off in the wrong direction blaming the immutable lists.

```
def lookup(list: List[Int], list2: List[(Char, List[Int])]): Option[String] = 
 list2.find(_._2 == list).map(_._1.toString)

/*
*Decode function for matching groups of bits in a list to characters    in     the HCodeMap
*@returns String
*/

 def decode(s: String, list: (List[Int], List[(Char, List[Int])])): String = {

  var s = ""
  var accum = 1
  var listp1 = list._1
  val listp2 = list._2

  while (!listp1.isEmpty) {

    lookup(listp1.take(accum), listp2) match {
      case Some(m) =>
        println(accum)
        s = s ++ m
        Log.d("MyTAG", "de" + s)
        listp1 = listp1.drop(accum)
        accum = 1
      case None =>
        accum = accum + 1
    }
  }
  s
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but as you say a codereview is in order as this is maybe 30 seconds faster than my code. It's of a much higher quality than mine so i'll give you the upvote as the correct answer and thanks for advising me that the immutable lists aren't the problem, just my sloppy code :D

Comment: Making `s` a StringBuilder might help quite a bit

Comment: I applaud @TheArchetypalPaul's efforts. Well done.  Looking over `decode`'s signature and basic algorithm, I can't help but wonder if it can't be done via `foldLeft`.  A rather complicated `foldLeft` for sure, but not unmanageable.

Comment: I had a think about that. It seemed more complicated than it was worth. I may have another go if I get bored :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be fast, your starting point is wrong. You should be working directly with the stream of bits, as opposed to your list of integers with each integer containing one bit. Somewhere you are wasting time converting the incoming bits to a list of integers, and then wasting a lot of time decoding that list.

One way to make a fast Huffman decoder is to build decoding tables that permit direct indexed lookups. Pick a number of bits, *n*, that would be about the length of a uniform code. E.g. if you have 256 symbols, lets start with *n* as eight. (You can mess with *n* later to optimize the speed.)

Now build a 256-entry table, which is indexed by the next eight bits of input. Each entry indicates that either a) the next code is eight bits or less, or b) the next code is nine bits or more in length. For a), the table tells you the number of bits in the code and the symbol it decodes to. In that case you remove that many bits from the stream and emit the symbol.

For b) the table points to the next table to index with subsequent bits and how many bits that is. You then discard eight bits from the stream and index the subtable which will also indicate a) or b). Though probably two levels of tables will be optimal, so the sub table will always indicate a), completing the decoding and emitting a symbol. In that case the size, i.e. number of bits in the index, for a subtable is the length of the longest code, minus eight, that has the prefix of the eight bits that indexed the main table.

The tables are straightforward to build, and the build is done just once with many uses, making its build time well worthwhile. Entries in the table are often repeated many times. E.g. a four-bit code would be repeated 16 times in the base eight-bit table.

You would use bit operations on a bit buffer, an integer, that pulls bytes from the stream as needed to keep it loaded with enough bits to form the next index. Simple bit shifts would move the bits down as they are used, and bit shifts up on the input bytes would be done before or'ing them into the bit buffer.

Once you get it all working, you can vary *n* and time the decoder with representative input to find the optimal value for *n*.